# MSYS2 and Mingw-w64: pacman cannot resolve host; can I download packages manually?

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, package-managers, msys2

After successfully installing MSYS2, running `pacman -Syu` I get these errors:

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
error: failed to update mingw32 (download library error)
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
error: failed to update mingw64 (download library error)
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'msys.db' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
error: failed to update msys (download library error)
error: failed to synchronize any databases
error: failed to init transaction (download library error)
```

If I copy one of those addresses (e.g. http://repo.msys2.org/) in the browser address bar, I can reach it.

How can I fix these errors? Could it depend on my company's firewall? Is there a way to manually download MSYS2 packages and install them from my hard-disk?

What I need are development tools like GCC, Clang, debugger, linker, libraries, ...

Platform: Windows 7.

Comment: You can manually download packages from [repo.msys2.org](http://repo.msys2.org/) but getting all the packages you need for a fully updated system and installing them in the right order will be a huge pain.  (You can install a downloaded package with `pacman -U pkg_filename.tar.gz`)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this requires a proxy setup

please have a look into https://gist.github.com/roblogic/b401aa68d0a7c7c96095fa64a7c9f684

for windows try to install CNTLM and configure a proxy server or contact your network administrator.

http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/